# CS0103 The name 'class' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I have a class to store command line arguments:

```
namespace ProjName
{
    public class CommandLineArguments
    {
        public static string[] Args { get; set; }
    }
}
```

in Program.cs I'm storing args in it:

```
using ProjName.DAL;

namespace ProjName
{
    class Program
    {
     static string ENVR = string.Empty;
     static void Main(string[] args)
        {
    
                    CommandLineArguments.Args = args;
                     //I access it couple of places in the application
                    ENVR = CommandLineArguments.Args[0].ToString().ToUpper();
        }
    
    }
}
```

Sometimes the class compiles and the code works fine. But other times it starts throwing error:

CS0103  The name 'CommandLineArguments' does not exist in the current context. I am referencing the class in Program.cs and wherever else I use it. Can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: How are you compiling the code? Are they in the same project, or different projects? If they're in different projects, is there a reference from your project containing `Program` to the one containing `CommandLineArguments`?

Comment: Same project. I'm compiling used Debug mode and then Release mode

Comment: If it's the same project, the only thing I can think of is that the class you are calling from has a different namespace and you need to "using" CommandLineArguments's namespace. Can you [edit] your post with a [mre]?

Comment: what do you mean as "I am referencing the class in Program.cs and wherever else I use it"? as long the class module belongs the same project, there's no need to do anything.

Comment: I'm confused by _"But other times it starts throwing error:"_.  Are you saying you are getting a compilation error or an exception (throw implies an exception, but "CS0103" looks like a compilation error)?  If a compiler error, are you saying you get a compilation error inconsistently?

Comment: "I'm compiling used Debug mode" - *how* though? In Visual Studio? You haven't told us anything about how you're compiling the code.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio to compile the code. Sometimes it compiles fine and stops throwing that error. Then I switch to Release mode to deploy the code and then it starts throwing error. Again, if I switch back to Debug mode, it starts throwing error

Comment: Another observation. I moved the declaration public static string[] Args { get; set; } to another class and it is not throwing error. or if I put it in the same namespace as Program.cs it is not throwing any error.

Comment: This will require a [mre]. Though while you figure that out you will highly likely find the reason.

Comment: Tbh why are you even using a class like this when you can access these things via `args`? I think it would make more sense to create a class to store the actual information you need. `public class PlatformInfo { public string ENVR { get; set; } = default!; }` + whatever other properties you deem useful?

Answer (score -4):

You may have to declare it first in main class
`CommandLineArguments CommandLineArguments = new CommandLineArguments();`

Comment: Why would that be necessary to access a static property?

Comment: Because the class is not declared as static.

Comment: That doesn't matter. The property is static. You don't need an instance of the class to access a class's static members.